# how to write a windows batch script to copy some files and folders from location A to B based on a variable like server name

Tags: windows

how to write a windows batch script to copy some files and folders from location A to B based on a variable like the server name?

Comment: What have you tried? Users here are more likely to help if you do your own research and show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor (for example the Windows built-in Notepad) to store the commands you would type on the commandline in a file. Save that file with the extension ".bat" or ".cmd".

The command you'll probably want to use is "copy" or "xcopy". You can learn more about how to call them by calling them with "/?". Example:

```
copy /?
```

To learn more about environment variables, try:

```
set /?
```